# How to migrate data on nestjs on prod by typeorm without use .env file

Tags: nestjs, migration, typeorm, database-migration, nestjs-typeorm

I use nestjs and typeorm migrate data. I use config look like:

```
const baseDir = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod' ? 'dist/src' : 'src';

export const makeDataSourceOptions = (): DataSourceOptions => {
  const dataSource: DataSourceOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST ?? '__DATABASE_HOST__',
    port: parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT ?? '5432', 10),
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER ?? '__DATABASE_USER__',
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD ?? '__DATABASE_PASSWORD__',
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB ?? '__DATABASE_NAME__',
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    migrations: [baseDir + '/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
    logging: true,
    synchronize: false,
  };

  return dataSource;
};
```

Config doten:

```
config({
  path:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? __dirname + '/../../.env.prod'
      : __dirname + '/../../.env.dev',
});
```

When i migrate on develop , i must input all information env on **.env.dev** , running command **export NODE_ENV=dev**  and running command **yarn migration:up** . It migrate success.
But when i migrate prod , i must input all information env on **.env.prod** , **export NODE_ENV=dev** and run  **yarn migration:up** .
Is there a better way to do this? Because every time I migrate I have to edit the .env.prod file. If I use services like cloud run, is there a better way than manually editing environment variables in files like .env.prod? Please help

Comment: Do you mean auto-run migration files when in production?

Answer (score 0):

My case is to add the option like this below:

```
  migrationsRun: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
```

this will auto-run all migration files when in the production environment